# How to hide textfield when output is null?

Tags: jasper-reports

I have problem with my report. I write my output with text and parameter. When I put the parameter. The result will show the text and parameter. But the problem is when I'm not key in the parameter, the result still show textfield for the output. I'm doing in java. I don't know what's the problem.

This is my code:

```java
(($P{daterangefrom} != null) && ($P{daterangeto}!=null) ) ? 
" From ( " + $P{daterangefrom} + " - " + $P{daterangeto} + " )"
 : null
```

Anyone know what wrong with my formula.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You must make sure that the parameter's value is not empty.

You can make the check with help of [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) library, for example.

The sample:

```java
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport ..>
    <import value="com.google.common.base.*"/>
    <parameter name="daterangefrom" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="daterangeto" class="java.lang.String"/>

    <title>
        <band height="79" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement x="185" y="12" width="100" height="20"  isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[(!Strings.isNullOrEmpty($P{daterangefrom}) &&
    !Strings.isNullOrEmpty($P{daterangeto})) ?
" From ( " + $P{daterangefrom} + " - " + $P{daterangeto} + " )"
 : null]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </title>
</jasperReport>
```

Do not forget about the ***`isRemoveLineWhenBlank`*** and ***`isBlankWhenNull`*** textField's properties.

Comment: Thank you very much. you are so much helpful.Thank you for your answer.:)

Comment: i have one more question,i have try to  put input date to and date from when the first time i  enter the parameter. When i put data on two parameter. That is date to and date from, the data is display. But the problem is when i put one data of two parameter. The data also display. how to give the error message when i put only one parameter.The data only show when two parameter is matching.